# Possibilities for IPC between two python scripts without using any external libraries

Tags: python, process, ipc

I am a very python beginner. I want to ask what are different ways to communicate between two python scripts without using any external supported libraries. One possibility is the Unix-Socket. But if there are any other ways please share. Another possibility is using Multiprocessing. But Multiprocessing library is to communicate between different processes in a single python program as I know. 
N.B: I am limited to the built-in libraries.

Thanks in advance
Anamika

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/ipc.html

Comment: Named pipes (fifo's) can be simple, use one for each direction.  The advantage is that you just use the normal Python IO statements.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/xmlrpclib.html might be worth looking at. It depends what sort of 'communication' you really need. Another (simple) way would be a shared file with a known name.

Comment: Yes I know that's also another possibility with pickle or json. Thanks. Now I will have a look into rpc. RPC is also a good idea.

Comment: @cdarke Sorry not to mention. I also know this. If there is any other possibility please share.